# Vuex action is not adding localstorage token to Axios post call

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex, vuex-modules

I am using flask as my backend server.
vuex action is not setting token from local storage state to Axios API call. Please help me with what am I missing. currently I am stuck here, this is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920501/when-using-axios-interceptors-api-calls-are-looping-for-401-error) which I dint get answer so posting again..
Below is my vuex store code:

```js
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    // accessToken: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access_token')) || null,
    // refreshToken: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')) || null,
    accessToken: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
    refreshToken: localStorage.getItem('refresh_token') || null,
    APIData: '',
  },
actions: {
refreshToken(context) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(context.state.refreshToken);
        getAPI.post('/refresh', {
          // refresh_token: context.state.refreshToken,
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${context.state.refreshToken}` },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log('New access token granted');
            context.commit('updateAccessToken', response.data.access_token);
            console.log(context.state.accessToken);
            resolve(response.data.access_token);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('\'error in refresh:\'', error);
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    },
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Vuex expert but I have used it several times.  Try initializing your state values to constants as place holders, and create mutations (if synchronous) or actions (if asynchronous) to call ```localStorage.getItem()```.

Comment: @Tim can you provide an example ?

Comment: Just saw your request for an example from 11 hours ago (it's morning here).  Let me know via comment if you resolve it over the next 8 hours.  If not, I will try to look at it this evening.

Comment: Hi, Not yet resolved. not really good with js. looking forward for example. complete code is available in my previous post i added it in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that I built with a simplified Vuex store and Vue component in order to demonstrate the functionality.

/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    accessToken: '',
    localStorage: window.localStorage
  },
  getters: {
    getTokenFromLocalStorage: state => {
      return state.localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    storeTokenInLocalStorage(state, newToken) {
      state.accessToken = newToken;
      state.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', newToken);
    }
  }
})
```

VuexLocalStorage.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="vuex-local-storage">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="getAccessToken">Get Access Token</button>
        <h5>{{ accessToken }}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        accessToken: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getAccessToken() {
        this.accessToken = this.$store.getters.getTokenFromLocalStorage;
      }
    },
    created() {
      // Store initial access token
      this.$store.commit('storeTokenInLocalStorage', 'access-token');
    }
  }
</script>
```